# Geting number between two values

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to get number between two values or these values? 
for example:

```
min: 10, max: 100
(in -> out)

   1 -> 10
   5 -> 10
  10 -> 10
  50 -> 50
 100 -> 100
1000 -> 100
9999 -> 100
```

now I'm using this:

```js
Math.max(10, Math.min(100, value));
```

but is there a more efficient and/or elegant way to do this?

Comment: It's called clamping.  Your way is perfectly efficient/elegant IMO, but you could always turn it into a function.

Comment: `value<10?10:value>100?100:value`

Comment: @James McLaughlin, thanks, I didn't know this name, now google showing me much more results than before ;-)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin , turn it into question on SO

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but here's a reusable solution:

```
function clamper(min, max) {
    return function(v) {
        return v > max ? max : (v < min ? min : v);
    };
}

var clamp = clamper(0, 100);

console.log(clamp(25));
console.log(clamp(50));
console.log(clamp(74));
console.log(clamp(120));
console.log(clamp(-300));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mx3whct6/

Answer (score 0):

No, there's really no better way than that. It's probably what I'd go with. If you really want an alternative, you could use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```
value > 100 ? 100 : value < 10 ? 10 : value;
```

However, I find this is a lot harder to read than a simple `min` / `max`.

Of course, if you find yourself doing this a lot, you can make your own function for brevity:

```
function clamp(val, min, max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val));
}
```

Then just use it like this:

```
clamp(value, 10, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

James is right.  Check [this](http://strd6.com/2010/08/useful-javascript-game-extensions-clamp/) for detail

```
/**
 * Returns a number whose value is limited to the given range.
 *
 * Example: limit the output of this computation to between 0 and 255
 * (x * 255).clamp(0, 255)
 *
 * @param {Number} min The lower boundary of the output range
 * @param {Number} max The upper boundary of the output range
 * @returns A number in the range [min, max]
 * @type Number
 */
Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
};
```